# What are the best practices for how to organize API calls and other functions?

Tags: angular, api, refactoring

This is more a general question, but I have a service **DocumentCorrespondenceService** with the endpoints like this:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: Router) { }


getDossierEntry(patientUUID: string,   type: String = '' ): Observable<DossierEntry[]> {
  const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;
  return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/${patientUUID}/DossierEntry/` + entryType);
}

getDossierEntryFileData(patientUUID: string, entryID: number ): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
  return this.http.get('https://dev-engine.mijnhep.nl/api/patient/${patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryID + '/fileData', {
    responseType: 'blob',
    observe: 'response'
  });
```

and I have a component with functions. But these functions will be triggered by other components.

```
 gotoItem(index, type: string) {
    this.showingSingle = true;

    switch (type) {
      case 'correspondence': {
        this.single = this.correspondenceEntries[index];
        break;
      }
      case 'attachments': {
        this.single = this.attachmentEntries[index];
        break;
      }
      default: {
        break;
      }
    }
    this.showingSingle = true;
  }

  goBack() {
    this.showingSingle = false;
  }
```

**My question is: what is the usual way to do this?**

rename: DocumentCorrespondenceService  to

```
DocumentCorrespondenceApiService
```

and a other service:

```
DocumentCorrespondenceService
```

with the functions in it. And in the component who use that function inject the:

```
DocumentCorrespondenceService
```

So that you have two services:

one for the api calls and a second one for the functions.

Thank you

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but after re-reading your question a few times, it's not at all clear what you're asking. "what is the usual way to do" what, exactly?

Comment: That you make two services: one for you api calls. And one for your functions that you will use in other components

Comment: And for example you have 100 endpoints. Is it then oke to put all your endpoints in one file. Or organise them on category. So to put them in seperate files.

Comment: Narm. And so what is your advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of things to consider. In reference to your comment about a service having 100 endpoints, you're probably going to want to divide it up a little bit. Here is a link directly to a style guide, which offers suggestions on how you should organize your code and shape your project.

https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#rule-of-one

Use the guide to form your own opinions about what works and doesn't work for your project. Also, don't create files for the sake of creating files, If your API calls and functions for handling the responses to those calls can exist in the same service, then do it. If maintaining the code becomes cumbersome and the file grows too large, then split it up into something manageable.